# Check if date between two others

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have the following row in a table:

```
id booking start               end
 3     325 2015-01-01 00:00:00 2015-01-09 00:00:00
```

Using the following query I attempt to find rows where a specified date is between two others:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE booking=$product AND $from between start and end
```

Which is parsed to the following when run:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_ovalbit_utils WHERE booking=325 AND 2015-02-01 between start and end
```

Obviously this should return that row, however it doesn't.

This is my schema:

```
id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
booking text NOT NULL,
start datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
end datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY id (id)
```

Comment: You're missing these (')

Comment: Oh yes, and 02-01 is 1st feb

Answer (score 2):

You forgot quotes around the date and to escape reserved words like `end`

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_ovalbit_utils 
WHERE booking = 325 
AND '2015-02-01 00:00:00' between `start` and `end`
```

BTW 1st for February is **not** between the two example dates.

Comment: The date format is yyyy-dd-mm, so that's the second of January

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. Since people were entering it in dd/mm/yyyy I assumed that date would keep the right order. That was part of what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a following WHERE clause.

```
WHERE `start` < $from AND $from < `end`;
```

I can't say for sure if the columns can be used in a BETWEEN statement (at least, i've never used a BETWEEN that way around).

PS. Be aware of SQL-injection that may be possible by using variables directly. See http://wiki.hashphp.org/Validation

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_ovalbit_utils 
WHERE booking=325 
AND `start` < '2015-02-01 00:00:00' AND `end` > '2015-02-01 00:00:00'
```

so, basically your date should be more than the start date and less than the end date